# Visual Studio debug issue

Tags: visual-studio-2008

When I try to debug my web application I get the below lines and output is not displayed. Can anybody help?

```
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\9.0\WebDev.WebServer.exe', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\WebDev.WebHost\9.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\WebDev.WebHost.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Drawing\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Drawing.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_32\System.Web\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Web.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Xml\2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Xml.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
The program '[528] WebDev.WebServer.EXE: Managed' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: By saying output i meant that my default.aspx page is not displayed...When i run the application ,,, above mentioned lines are displayed in the small output window instead of my default.aspx....Is there a issue in my code or it has got to do with visual studio...Thank you for your concern...